# Liberal date/time parsing in Joda-Time

Tags: java, parsing, jodatime

Is it possible to create a single `DateTimeParser` which would parse:

- dates with time given
- dates without time (assuming time to be start of day)
- times without dates (assuming date to be today)

or do I need to have three separate parsers, and try parsing strings with each one?

In other words, is it possible to define optional fields in a parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat` has a static method `dateOptionalTimeParser()` that uses the code below, based on the `DateTimeFomatterBuilder` class, which has an `appendOptional` method - you would probably be able to adapt the method to your requirement... Link: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html

```
public static DateTimeFormatter dateOptionalTimeParser() {
    if (dotp == null) {
        DateTimeParser timeOrOffset = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendLiteral('T')
            .appendOptional(timeElementParser().getParser())
            .appendOptional(offsetElement().getParser())
            .toParser();
        dotp = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(dateElementParser())
            .appendOptional(timeOrOffset)
            .toFormatter();
    }
    return dotp;
}
```