# Liberal date/time parsing in Pig

Tags: datetime, apache-pig, jodatime

(Related to [Liberal date/time parsing in Joda-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9308977/liberal-date-time-parsing-in-joda-time))

Hey,
We're dealing with a pig column that contains mixed date formats: for some records its `09/11/2004 00:00:00`, and for some records its `09/11/2004 00:00:00.000000`.

We tried parsing it using pig11 `ToDate` (which internally uses jodatime's `DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DataType.toString(input.get(1)));`

- `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` we get `Invalid format: "12/31/1969 00:00:00" is too short at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime`
- `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.000000` we get `Invalid format: "09/25/2009 00:00:00.000000" is malformed at ".000000"`

Can you suggest a time-format that will handle both? Do we need to use a custom ToDate function?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't suppose you can fix your data to only contain a single format? That would be better than working around the issue. (Or don't store date/time values as strings in the first place... I don't know enough about Pig to know whether that's a sensible suggestion...)

Comment: We can't change the data as we're not responsible for creating it, and there's already heaps of it with this unfortunate format :(

Comment: Hmm. I think this can be done via a formatter built with the DateTimeFormatterBuilder. Will experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` to achieve this with an optional part:

```
import org.joda.time.format.*;

class Test {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter formatter =
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormat.forPattern(".SSSSSS").getParser())
            .toFormatter();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        testParse("09/11/2004 00:00:00");
        testParse("09/11/2004 00:00:00.000000");
    }

    private static void testParse(String input) {
        System.out.println(formatter.parseLocalDateTime(input));
    }
}
```